# unnest_tokens fails to handle vectors in R with tidytext package

Tags: r, text-analysis, tidytext

I want to use the `tidytext` package to create a column with 'ngrams'. with the following code:

```
library(tidytext)

unnest_tokens(tbl = president_tweets,
              output =  bigrams,
              input = text,
              token = "ngrams", 
              n = 2)
```

But when I run this I get the following error message:

```
error: unnest_tokens expects all columns of input to be atomic vectors (not lists)
```

My `text` column consists of a lot of tweets with rows that look like the following and is of class character.

```
president_tweets$text <– c("The United States Senate just passed the biggest in history Tax Cut and Reform Bill. Terrible Individual Mandate (ObamaCare)Repealed. Goes to the House tomorrow morning for final vote. If approved, there will be a News Conference at The White House at approximately 1:00 P.M.", 
    "Congratulations to Paul Ryan, Kevin McCarthy, Kevin Brady, Steve Scalise, Cathy McMorris Rodgers and all great House Republicans who voted in favor of cutting your taxes!", 
    "A  story in the @washingtonpost that I was close to rescinding the nomination of Justice Gorsuch prior to confirmation is FAKE NEWS. I never even wavered and am very proud of him and the job he is doing as a Justice of the U.S. Supreme Court. The unnamed sources dont exist!", 
    "Stocks and the economy have a long way to go after the Tax Cut Bill is totally understood and appreciated in scope and size. Immediate expensing will have a big impact. Biggest Tax Cuts and Reform EVER passed. Enjoy, and create many beautiful JOBS!", 
    "DOW RISES 5000 POINTS ON THE YEAR FOR THE FIRST TIME EVER - MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN!", 
    "70 Record Closes for the Dow so far this year! We have NEVER had 70 Dow Records in a one year period. Wow!"
    )
```

**---------Update:----------**

It looks like the `sentimetr` or `exploratory` package caused the conflict. I reloaded my packages without these and now it works again!

Comment: Do you have a `vector` or `data.frame`.  Based on the info, it is working for me.  Assuming that 'text' is the column name and 'president_tweets' is a `data.frame`.  Check the `str(president_tweets)`.  If the 'text' column is a `list`, convert it to a `vector` by `unlist`ing

Comment: `str()` says `$ text      : chr` that would be a vector right?

Comment: It is working for me

Comment: Something is messed up with the way you load libraries? Could it be that `president_tweets` is a list? `president_tweets` should be a `tibble` or a `data.frame`, containing a `text` column. Once you ensure that, everything else will follow.

Comment: The `president_tweets` is a tibble that has the column `text`. First this `text` column consisted of lists of sentences. But I `unlist`ed the stences column resulting in the `text` column which is now a character vector...

Comment: Posting `dput(head(president_tweets))` is an effective way to share the structure of your data in a copy/pasteable way.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm, I am not able to reproduce your problem.

```r
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

president_tweets <- data_frame(text = c("The United States Senate just passed the biggest in history Tax Cut and Reform Bill. Terrible Individual Mandate (ObamaCare)Repealed. Goes to the House tomorrow morning for final vote. If approved, there will be a News Conference at The White House at approximately 1:00 P.M.", 
                                        "Congratulations to Paul Ryan, Kevin McCarthy, Kevin Brady, Steve Scalise, Cathy McMorris Rodgers and all great House Republicans who voted in favor of cutting your taxes!", 
                                        "A  story in the @washingtonpost that I was close to rescinding the nomination of Justice Gorsuch prior to confirmation is FAKE NEWS. I never even wavered and am very proud of him and the job he is doing as a Justice of the U.S. Supreme Court. The unnamed sources dont exist!", 
                                        "Stocks and the economy have a long way to go after the Tax Cut Bill is totally understood and appreciated in scope and size. Immediate expensing will have a big impact. Biggest Tax Cuts and Reform EVER passed. Enjoy, and create many beautiful JOBS!", 
                                        "DOW RISES 5000 POINTS ON THE YEAR FOR THE FIRST TIME EVER - MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN!", 
                                        "70 Record Closes for the Dow so far this year! We have NEVER had 70 Dow Records in a one year period. Wow!"))


unnest_tokens(tbl = president_tweets,
              output =  bigrams,
              input = text,
              token = "ngrams", 
              n = 2) 
#> # A tibble: 205 x 1
#>    bigrams      
#>    <chr>        
#>  1 the united   
#>  2 united states
#>  3 states senate
#>  4 senate just  
#>  5 just passed  
#>  6 passed the   
#>  7 the biggest  
#>  8 biggest in   
#>  9 in history   
#> 10 history tax  
#> # ... with 195 more rows
```

The current CRAN version of tidytext does in fact not allow list-columns but we have changed the column handling so that the development version on GitHub now supports list-columns. Are you sure you don't have any of these in your data frame/tibble? What are the data types of all of your columns? Are any of them of type `list`?

Comment: Hi Julia, I deleted the `sentimentr` and `exploratory` packages which I didn't need anymore anyway. It seems those packages were causing the conflicts. Thnx for your answer though!